# Configure Eclipse 3.7 with MinGW?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, mingw

I have eclipse helios 3.7 and MinGW on windows 7 OS. Eclipse comes with no C/C++ compiler so I need to configure Eclipse with MinGW. How to do this?

Comment: There are many resources on the web on this one, but if my memory serves me right it was as simple as: Download and install MinGW; Download and install Eclipse CDT; Start Eclipse and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the MinGW\bin path to the path variable, so that eclipse can find it.