# Configuring Eclipse for MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I am using Eclipse Juno with MinGW (latest version) on my Win7-Laptop.
My example code is successfully built within the IDE, but I can neither run nor debug it!

When I choose Run as=>Local C/C++-Application, I get

> Launch failed. Binary not found.

However, there IS an exe-file as a result of the build process!

When I call cmd.exe, navigate to the source directory and call this built exe (a.out.exe), it works without problems!

I guess this is due to wrong/missing configuration of eclipse, but I couldn't find useful info on that so far.
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884243/configure-eclipse-3-7-with-mingw) mentions environment variables. I added MinGW and Msys to my PATH variable (that's why I can compile) but I can't run my software in eclipse!

So, what can be done to enable debugging?

Comment: Do you just need gcc? If so do yourself a big favor. Put linux in a VM and run eclipse there. Your life will be way better.

Comment: For the sake of portability I can't use only gcc and I don't feel eager to struggle with cross compiling. The product has to run on both windows and linux. So far I'm fine with using eclipse/gcc on linux and VisualC++ (student licence) on windows

Answer (score 5):

**I have made a little tutorial.**
how to set all for Eclipse have a look it's here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12169583/1322642

Hope it can help you a little bit.

Comment: @bogus ; Now , Have you take a look at that ?