# how do the eclipse cpp find the mingw install path?

Tags: c++, mingw

how do the eclipse cpp find the mingw install path?

I can't configure the mingw path into envrionment path, but how can the eclipse cpp ide find the mingw?

**Edit:**

Try this:
Windows -> preferences-> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment

but what should I add key-value into Environment

Comment: I searched for [eclipse mingw](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eclipse+mingw), first result was [Eclipse, CDT & MingW Setup Guide](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Eclipse,_CDT_%26_MingW_Setup_Guide). Second result was [Configuring Eclipse for MinGW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627481/configuring-eclipse-for-mingw).

Comment: @Peter Wood, I wonder how you didn't close this question...

Comment: but what should I add key-value into Environment

Comment: @user1764961 There are no accepted answers at the other end of the link.

Comment: You can check the configuration for the toolchain inside eclipse. That will tell you what it will call to compile. If that only mentions the compiler (without a path) then it means that your PATH environment variable includes the directory where the compiler is installed. If that contains the exact path (I doubt it) then there must be something else going on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, last time I used it, it was expecting MinGW in C:\MinGW by default.

Comment: but my path is c:\mingw2,it is ok too. why?

Comment: Yes, it is, but you have to enter that path in Eclipse somewhere... I don't really remember where exactly :-(

Comment: I just made a stupid mistake. I edited your question instead of my answer. Anyway, try this: Windows -> preferences-> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment

Comment: but what should I add key-value into Environment?

Comment: try entering the path to your mingw installation...

Comment: your answer isn't full.

Comment: @Peter Wood and the rest of the "smart" crew, what part of the question: "how do the eclipse cpp find the mingw install path?" makes it difficult for you to tell what is being asked here? You are closing every question that you know nothing about. You are a real troll.